# Python: linguistic normalization

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm looking for a lemmatization module/lib that will transfer a sentence like:
 "this is **great**" to "this is **good**".

I'm familiar with some of the tools available in nltk such as stemming and lemmatization, however it's not exactly what I'm looking for

My goal is to minimize the variety of ways saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it.

1) You can use a predefined set of synonyms to replace words, like WordNet. You can use the WordNet corpus using the `nltk` package.

nltk documentation has a well explained example of [this](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

This approach will only cover predefined synonyms and will not "learn" similar concepts from the data you are using. For example, crane could be a vehicle or a bird.

2) Another way is to use LSA which identifies similar concepts from the usage of words in the corpus.

If you think of text as vectors of words (every word in the corpus), your vectors have V dimensions where V is the total number of unique words in your corpus. Meaning, the problem you're trying to solve is of dimensionality reduction. LSA works well for dimensionality reduction.

Read more about LSA on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis).

You can use the LSA method by using [sklearn's TruncatedSVD class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more experimental, but another possibility is to use word embeddings.

The words *great* and *good* should have similar occurrence contexts, so their vectors should be similar, you cluster your words like that, and aggregate them into the same word/concept.

Of course this will greatly depend on the corpus and methods you use to generate the embeddings.

Comment: I would definitely look into word embeddings such as word2vec as opposed to LSA if the collection is sufficiently large